# Using ServiceStack to register multiple handlers to RabbitMq is causing massive slowdowns during startup

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, servicestack

I have a .NET app that uses ServiceStack to bind service adapters to corresponding queues within RabbitMQ, in a very similar manner to the examples provided here - https://docs.servicestack.net/rabbit-mq

However, when I register more than ~30 services, I begin to see a massive slowdown during startup. Digging into the logs, it appears that RabbitMQ is being swamped with lots of connections in a very short amount of time, cause our binding requests to continuously timeout. This has caused our startup time to go from ~15 seconds to over 5 minutes

```
class MQAppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public MQAppHost() : base("MQServices", typeof(ServiceAdapters.ServiceAdapters))
        { }

        public override void OnAfterInit()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "localhost",
                Port = 5672,
                UserName = "guest",
                Password = "guest"
            };

            RabbitMqMessageFactory mqMessageFactory = new RabbitMqMessageFactory(factory);

            RabbitMqServer mqServer = new RabbitMqServer(mqMessageFactory)
            {
                AutoReconnect = true
            };

            mqServer.RegisterHandler<Model1>(x => { return x.GetBody(); });
            mqServer.RegisterHandler<Model2>(x => { return x.GetBody(); });
            mqServer.RegisterHandler<Model3>(x => { return x.GetBody(); });
            //...
            mqServer.RegisterHandler<Model48>(x => { return x.GetBody(); });
            mqServer.RegisterHandler<Model49>(x => { return x.GetBody(); });
            mqServer.RegisterHandler<Model50>(x => { return x.GetBody(); });

            mqServer.Start();

            base.OnAfterInit();
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        { }
    }
```

ServiceStack logs

> DEBUG|RabbitMqServer|Starting all Rabbit MQ Server worker threads...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model1.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model2.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model3.inq...
> ...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model48.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model49.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model50.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqServer|Started Background Thread: Rabbit MQ Server 1
> ...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model23.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model22.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model25.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model24.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model26.inq...
> ERROR|RabbitMqServer|Received exception in Worker: mq:Model26.inq
> ERROR|RabbitMqServer|Received exception in Worker: mq:Model24.inq
> ERROR|RabbitMqServer|Received exception in Worker: mq:Model25.inq
> DEBUG|RabbitMqServer|Starting new mq:Model25.inq Worker at index 24...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqServer|Starting new mq:Model26.inq Worker at index 25...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model26.inq...
> ERROR|RabbitMqServer|Received exception in Worker: mq:Model23.inq
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model27.inq...
> ERROR|RabbitMqServer|Received exception in Worker: mq:Model27.inq
> DEBUG|RabbitMqServer|Starting new mq:Model27.inq Worker at index 26...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Starting MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model27.inq...
> DEBUG|RabbitMqWorker|Stopping Rabbit MQ Handler Worker: mq:Model30.inq...
> ...

RabbitMQ logs

> ...
> [info] <0.1064.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1064.0> ([::1]:63576 -> [::1]:5672)
> [info] <0.1048.0> connection <0.1048.0> ([::1]:63574 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
> [info] <0.1061.0> connection <0.1061.0> ([::1]:63575 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
> [info] <0.1064.0> connection <0.1064.0> ([::1]:63576 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
> [warning] <0.935.0> closing AMQP connection <0.935.0> ([::1]:63566 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.935.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.739.0> closing AMQP connection <0.739.0> ([::1]:63564 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.739.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.971.0> closing AMQP connection <0.971.0> ([::1]:63568 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.971.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.974.0> closing AMQP connection <0.974.0> ([::1]:63569 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.974.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.1003.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1003.0> ([::1]:63572 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.1003.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.938.0> closing AMQP connection <0.938.0> ([::1]:63567 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.938.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.932.0> closing AMQP connection <0.932.0> ([::1]:63565 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.932.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.1000.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1000.0> ([::1]:63571 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.1000.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.997.0> closing AMQP connection <0.997.0> ([::1]:63570 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.997.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.1048.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1048.0> ([::1]:63574 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.1048.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.1006.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1006.0> ([::1]:63573 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.1006.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.1064.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1064.0> ([::1]:63576 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> [warning] <0.1064.0> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> [warning] <0.1061.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1061.0> ([::1]:63575 -> [::1]:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
> ...

I am using the ServiceStack 6.9 nuget package alongside the RabbitMQ 6.5 nuget package

The RabbitMQ server is using the latest version of erlang, and is running on a windows machine with the latest rabbit mq release. I have tried using several different versions, they all exhibit the same behavior.

How can I avoid overloading rabbitmq with connection requests during startup, while still registering all my services?

Comment: Did  you tried making the RegistrationHandler Wait for each handler to complete the request .. to me what is happening is near simultaneous request swamping the RabbitMQ to open a connection which by far is a very resource intensive operation..

Comment: also see this ..https://docs.servicestack.net/rabbit-mq#allocating-multiple-threads-for-specific-operations

Comment: I don't see a way to make service stack wait when registering services, all of the requests are sent automatically when I run "mqServer.Start()"